# Does rejecting ads work during read-only mode?

Tags: support, advertising, read-only

During the recent read-only mode, ads were shown to me, because I was no longer a high-rep user, but a random surfer from the internet.

Does giving an ad a "Thumbs down", which gives a dialog box saying it won't be shown again, actually have any effect? I assume that if Stack Exchange is in read-only mode, then it can't, but that'd mean the dialog box was incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adzerk (our ad server) uses cookies to keep track of the down voted ads, which will persist (with all the usual cookie related caveats).